# Need to keep pressing the unlock button on a reciprocating saw: is that typical?

Tags: saw

I just got a modest cordless reciprocating saw by *SnapFresh*   [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B089QGR718/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089QGR718)

To run the thing we need to press *two* buttons at all times: not just the trigger but also that  "Lock" button highlighted in red:

[image]

The owner's manual confirms that both need to be depressed for us to get any juice.  So .. is this standard fare for a reciprocating saw?  It is awkward!

Comment: yes, the trigger lock has to be depressed before the trigger is pulled ... you should not have to keep the lock button depressed once the trigger is pulled

Comment: @jsotola ah ok - gotcha . Maybe everyone else on the planet figures that out without help. If you want to make that an answer i'd award

Comment: Have fun with your new tool!  Fine teeth for fine materials, be conscious of perpendicularity when cutting rod stock, and learn the feel of the right pressure that causes the tool to float through the work piece without chattering or overworking.  For cutting metal, high quality blades make a big difference.

Comment: @KH thanks the kid in me says I _would_ have fun.  But sprained an ankle last weekend (running) and the healing schedule conflicts with building timing so I  may not get to use these toys as much as expected. Bona fide contractors are starting to materialize to take care of business.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trigger lock is a mechanical safety mechanism that prevents the trigger from being pulled.

It needs to be depressed before the trigger can be pulled.

I would not activate the two buttons at exactly the same time, because I do not know it that would cause any wear on the unlock mechanism.

The trigger lock button is only used to allow the trigger switch to be pulled, so it does not have to be held when the trigger is pulled.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard on most cutting power tools. You don't want the tool to start to operate just because you reached over and grabbed it. So yes, you have to press both buttons to start it each time but then can release the trigger lock. My router,circular saw, reciprocating saw, table saw all have the same two button press. Be safe, don't try to jury rig it so you only need to press one. It's much harder to be a DIYer when you're missing fingers.

Comment: @jsotola added the crucial detail (to me) that the button only needs to be depressed when pulling the trigger but does not need to remain depressed afterwards